# Hide sidebar when viewport is too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hidding the sidebar with a button.

But when the view get's under 991px I want to hide the sidebar to have more space for my site.

How can i do this? If I put the code inside the if it will always be toggling. If the size is bigger than 991px it should show the sidebar again

```
   $('#sidebar-btn').click(function () {
   $('#sidebar').toggle('visible');
   $('.content-wrapper, .full-page-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper full-page-wrapper');
});

//toggle sidebar when width is too small
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
if(browserWidth <= 991 ) {

}
```

Comment: Why not hide it in your CSS with a media query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain CSS for that (***EDIT***: if you want to toogle classes you need JS).

```js
if(!($(window).width() <= 911)) {
  $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper');
  $('.full-page-wrapper').toggleClass('full-page-wrapper');
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 911px) {
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sidebar" class="content-wrapper full-page-wrapper">AAAAAAAAAA</section>
```

Comment: bad solution.. it just hides the sidebar. I need to toggle those classes to make the margin 0, etc...

Comment: @user9417998 try using toggle separately for each class

Answer (score 0):

You could try with css as follow :

```
@media (min-width:991px) {
    //Do your css things
}
```

Else you can catch [resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to get the width of the window.

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    alert('Less than 960');
} else {
    alert('More than 960');
}
```